# Make Multiple Strings with For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, for-loop

So I have a text file reader that reads in each string as they come in.

```
String R1Name = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R1URL = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R2 = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R2Name = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R2URL = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R3 = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R3Name = fileScanner.nextLine();
String R3URL = fileScanner.nextLine();
```

Etc.

How can I have it so it creates a simple for loop with number 1-7 that does the same thing with less code?

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){

            String R(i) = fileScanner.nextLine();
            String R(i)URL=fileScanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Trying to get something like this but with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
String[] R = new String[8];
String[] RUrl = new String[8];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    R[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
    RUrl[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
}
```